# Where-Object : The specified operator requires both the -Property and -Value parameters. Provide values for both parameters, and then try the

Tags: powershell, event-log, where-object

I'm doing the following powershell line, and for some reason it's finding a syntax error with it, but I'm not sure why, and I can't find it in an internet search:

```
 $eventInitTerminate = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ProviderName='chromoting';StartTime=$initTime;EndTime=$crashOccurredTime;} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object -PipelineVariable Message -Match 'Channel'
```

I can see Channel in my chromoting ProviderName for Application event-log, but for some reason it's not working here and I get the error message:

```
Where-Object : The specified operator requires both the -Property and -Value parameters. Provide values for both parameters, and then try the
command again.
At E:\dirName\CrashAfterExclude_test2.ps1:25 char:192
+ ... tlyContinue | Where-Object -PipelineVariable Message -Match 'Channel'
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueNotSpecifiedForWhereObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Comment: `Where-Object -PipelineVariable Message -Match 'Channel'` should be `Where-Object -Property Message -Match 'Channel'`. Unless your intent is to use the object down the pipeline as a whole, `-PipelineVariable` is out of place. It's currently being read as `Where-Object (-PipelineVariable Message) (-Match 'Channel)'` where `-Match` is expecting the property name.

Comment: You didn't name the pipeline variable.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I tried $eventInitTerminate = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ProviderName='chromoting';StartTime=$initTime;EndTime=$crashOccurredTime;} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object (-Property Message) (-Match 'Channel')
         and still get error -Property : The term '-Property' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: @js2010 what do you mean. The variable is part of the Get-WinEvent filterhashtable object returned. How do you recommend naming it? Wouldn't it just be a matter of accessing the data from the returned info? Isn't that what I'm doing? What else would I do differently?

Comment: `Where-Object -PipelineVariable myvar Message -Match 'Channel | % { echo $myvar }'
             `

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd fit that into the entire pipeline. Isn't Message the variable?  $eventInitTerminate = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ProviderName='chromoting';StartTime=$initTime;EndTime=$crashOccurredTime;} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object -PipelineVariable Message -Match 'Channel'

Comment: Message is the implied -property parameter.  I don't think you know what -pipelinevariable does.  You don't need the echo part.  That was just an example to understand it.  `Where-Object Message -Match 'Channel'`

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with this: $eventInitTerminate = {Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ProviderName='chromoting';StartTime=$initTime;EndTime=$crashOccurredTime;} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object -Property 'Message' -Match -Value 'Channel'